Does a Way of the Astral Self Monk HAVE to do force damage with Arms of the Astral Self from 10' away, or can it be bludgeoning?
Arms of the Astral Self says:


You can use the spectral arms to make unarmed strikes.
When you make an unarmed strike with the arms on your turn, your reach for it is 5 feet greater than normal.
The unarmed strikes you make with the arms can use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength or Dexterity modifier for the attack and damage rolls, and their damage type is force.


Does this mean that if you strike a target 10' away using the Arms, the damage inflicted HAS to be force damage? Or can you choose to just do your regular unarmed strike damage (such as bludgeoning)?

Is there a particular reason why you want to prefer bludgeoning damage type?

If nothing else, some creatures have vulnerability to bludgeoning damage.

Probably the Crusher feat.

Actually it was for a lizardfolk monk and slashing damage with the Slasher feat, but yes, same idea.

The arms do force damage regardless of what the monk chooses
"Can" is typically used in the rules to mean something that a player or character freely chooses; it introduces an option.  This could be followed by another option, and if the two are in the same sentence, the two parts might be joined by the conjunction "and".  If this second option is independent of the first, it will usually have its own "can", indicating another choice is to be freely made.  However, if the second option is dependent on the first, it will indicate this dependence, often through the phrase "if", or "if you do", or "when you do"1.
Understanding this, let's examine the monk ability:

You can use the spectral arms to make unarmed strikes.

"Can" means that this is an option.  The monk is permitted to make unarmed strikes with the spectral arms, but is not required to do so.  Nor does the use of this ability restrict the monk's option to make unarmed strikes as normal with their own body.

When you make an unarmed strike with the arms on your turn, your reach for it is 5 feet greater than normal.

"When" means what follows is dependent on the monk having made an unarmed strike with the arms on their turn.  If they do so, their reach for that strike is extended 5 feet.  If they do not, it is not.  They do not get to choose the distance of their reach, they only get to choose whether or not to use the astral arms to strike.

The unarmed strikes you make with the arms can use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength or Dexterity modifier for the attack and damage rolls, and their damage type is force.

"Can" means the monk may choose to use their Wis mod rather than Str or Dex for the attack and damage rolls; "and their damage type is force" means that the astral arms do only force damage, regardless of the choices of the monk at any other point.
If the arms did force damage when the monk chose Wisdom but otherwise did bludgeoning, it would say:

The unarmed strikes you make with the arms can use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength or Dexterity modifier for the attack and damage rolls, and if you do [or when you do] their damage type is force.

If the monk was free to choose the damage type of the arms, it would say:

The unarmed strikes you make with the arms can use your Wisdom modifier in place of your Strength or Dexterity modifier for the attack and damage rolls, and their damage type can be force.

Because of the specific language used in the ability, we know that the astral arms can do only force damage.  This makes sense, both because the arms themselves are astral, and because when they are initially summoned, they do only force damage:

As a bonus action, you can spend 1 ki point to summon the arms of your astral self.  When you do so, each creature of your choice that you can see within 10 feet of you must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or take force damage equal to two rolls of your Martial Arts die.


Language use example from dream
1 For example, the dream spell says (in part):

If the target is asleep, the messenger appears in the target's dreams and can converse with the target as long as it remains asleep, through the duration of the spell. The messenger can also shape the environment of the dream, creating landscapes, objects, and other images. The messenger can emerge from the trance at any time, ending the effect of the spell early. The target recalls the dream perfectly upon waking.

This section of the spell is introduced with "If the target is asleep".  These four sentences all have the same dependency - they apply only if the target of the spell is asleep.  One of the sentences, the last one, is required: "The target recalls the dream perfectly upon waking."  This will happen, regardless of whether the caster chooses any of the other options in this section.  The caster has three options, each indicated with can: "can converse", "can shape", and "can emerge".  Each of these options is independent; the caster can exercise any and all of them, and their decision for each option has no effect on their ability to exercise another.
The spell also says,

You can make the messenger appear monstrous and terrifying to the target. If you do, the messenger can deliver a message of no more than ten words and then the target must make a Wisdom saving throw.

Here are two "cans" joined by an "and" - but they are not independent.  The caster is free to make the messenger terrifying or not, but the messenger can only deliver a message that forces a saving throw if the caster does so.  Had this part of the spell left out the "if you do", then making the messenger terrifying and forcing the save would have been independent.  For example, had it been worded as:

You can make the messenger appear monstrous and terrifying to the target, and the messenger can deliver a message of no more than ten words and then the target must make a Wisdom saving throw.

Were this the wording, the caster could deliver a message that forces a save without making the messenger terrifying, but such a possibility is not permitted by the actual description of the spell.

I added a simple edit to better show that the second part is dependent on having chosen to use the spectral arms, not just on making any unarmed strike. Also, I think your description of the Dream spell's restrictions is not quite right: the messenger can always deliver a message, since they "... can converse with the target as long as it remains asleep"; what they cannot do, if they choose to appear as monstrous and terrifying, is deliver a message of more than ten words. Your explanation makes it seem as if the messenger could not talk to the target unless in monstrous shape.

@walen ty, edited
